# Python - turns string into dictionary where keys are subheadings and values are links

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

In the middle of some text I have the following.

```
Some random text before.

----CAPITAL WORDS:
first subheading
https://link1
https://link2

second subheading
https://link3

third subheading
https://link4
https://link5
https://link6
https://link7

----MORE CAPITAL WORDS:
Some random text after.
```

I would like to extract the string between `----CAPITAL WORDS:` and `----MORE CAPITAL WORDS` and store it in a dictionary as follows

```
{
    'first subheading': ["https://link1", "https://link2"],
    'second subheading': ["https://link3"]
    'third subheading': ["https://link4", "https://link5", "https://link6", "https://link7"]
}
```

## Attempt

```
pattern = r"CAPITAL WORDS:(.*?)(?:\n----MORE CAPITAL WORDS:|$)"
matches = re.search(pattern, descriptions[0], re.DOTALL)
lines = matches.group(1).strip().split("\n")

link_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    if line:
         pass # unsure how to continue
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: @Nesi added my attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have already processed `lines` to be:

```
['first subheading', 'https://link1', 'https://link2', '', 
 'second subheading', 'https://link3', '', 
 'third subheading', 'https://link4', 'https://link5', 
 'https://link6', 'https://link7']
```

You can do this concisely using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

{next(g): [*g] for k, g in groupby(lines, key=bool) if k}
# {'first subheading':  ['https://link1', 'https://link2'], 
#  'second subheading': ['https://link3'], 
#  'third subheading':  ['https://link4', 'https://link5', 'https://link6', 'https://link7']}
```

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: Wow! Do you mind explaining the groupby approach?

Comment: See the linked docs of `groupby`. This groups the lines by their truthiness (in groups of empty and non-empty lines). Then it takes the groups of non-empty ones and comprehends them into a `dict` using the first of each group as key and a list of the rest as value.

Comment: Consecutive lines are grouped by empty/non empty (key=bool); then the first line of each non empty group is used as dictionary key, the rest as values. Edit: @user2390182, you might want to move your explanation to the body of your answer.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `g` is a grouper object which is an iterator that is advanced by the `next` call, so that `[*g]` will then collect only the remainder into a list.

Comment: If you want to examine what's going on there: `[(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lines, key=bool)]` gives you a fully listified representation of all these lazy iterables.

Answer (score 1):

```
example = """Some random text before.

----CAPITAL WORDS:
first subheading
https://link1
https://link2

second subheading
https://link3

third subheading
https://link4
https://link5
https://link6
https://link7

----MORE CAPITAL WORDS:
Some random text after."""


out = {}
current_heading = None
for line in example.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('----'):
        pass
    elif line.startswith('http'):
        out[current_heading].append(line)
    elif line.islower():
        current_heading = line
        out[current_heading] = []
```

Output:

```
{'first subheading': ['https://link1', 'https://link2'], 
'second subheading': ['https://link3'], 
'third subheading': ['https://link4', 'https://link5', 'https://link6', 'https://link7']}
```

Answer (score 1):

To match `----CAPITAL WORDS:` and process all following parts without crossing either `----CAPITAL WORDS:` or `----MORE CAPITAL WORDS:` you could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and `captures()` for repeated capture groups.

```
(?:^----CAPITAL WORDS:\n|\G)(?!(----(?:MORE )?CAPITAL WORDS:))(?P<sub>\S.*)(?:\n(?!(?1))(?P<val>\S.*))+\s*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^----CAPITAL WORDS:\n` Match literally from the start of the string followed by a newline
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is directly to the right is not

  - `(----(?:MORE )?CAPITAL WORDS:)` Capture in **group 1**, matching `CAPITAL WORDS:` with an optional leading `MORE`  part
- `)` Close the negative lookahead
- `(?P<sub>\S.*)` Capture group **sub**, match the single lined subheading (starting with at least a single non whitespace char to prevent matching empty lines)
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!(?1))` Assert that the pattern of group 1 is not directly to the right
  - `(?P<val>\S.*)` Capture in group **val** the single lines values like "https://link1"
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1+ times
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piFIiu/1) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jZJdT8IwFIbv@ytqr1rEIeJHsqgLUWJIQAhgvGBoytaxRtYtbSEY9bfPw8cFCk561z7vefvmnJO92zhVtTyXSZZqi7WYiAVCGbdWaIVvsCbUc19O4NzVu81BvYWfO737vuurT/@BUe@ILhlo2p1eAzPvp4qBonttZuNbv@@U4AJ1yxqvuiZzPl0TduybEkHIwJeU9NNEYM1VmCbYioXFYxGlWji@8hVBeOuQfcl@SSKpjcUQIhY8lGqyI4itzYxbqUyleqsW0rM9CYwIUhUe6l/b42BjqQ82OC@kF4X0spBe/dHe1WT/6fHOxHgEC@QQhlDCbRCL5WBXy@VEUoUSIN0sWRmb8ga1n1qDZqv52GAoDCxUfHwhGDx@LeMES4WFmiVCcyvoxpS5qxggHiZOwDM708JQAq0kbHg6GoHF9jusGyTKtFSWQg3L828).

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:^----CAPITAL WORDS:\n|\G)(?!(----(?:MORE )?CAPITAL WORDS:))(?P<sub>\S.*)(?:\n(?!(?1))(?P<val>\S.*))+\s*"

s = ("Some random text before.\n\n"
            "----CAPITAL WORDS:\n"
            "first subheading\n"
            "https://link1\n"
            "https://link2\n\n"
            "second subheading\n"
            "https://link3\n\n"
            "third subheading\n"
            "https://link4\n"
            "https://link5\n"
            "https://link6\n"
            "https://link7\n\n"
            "----MORE CAPITAL WORDS:\n"
            "Some random text after.")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, s, regex.MULTILINE)
dct = {}
for _, m in enumerate(matches):
    dct[m.captures("sub")[0]] = m.captures("val")
print(dct)
```

Output

```
{
'first subheading': ['https://link1', 'https://link2'],
'second subheading': ['https://link3'],
'third subheading': ['https://link4', 'https://link5', 'https://link6', 'https://link7']
}
```